# Why is the first line of output printed with last line of input, and last line of input not printing as a result?

Tags: python, input

I am solving an archived Google Codejam problem, but my question isn't directly related to the problem. It relates to the formatting of the input, which is causing one less input to run than I would like, and I have come across this problem many times, and am not sure how to fix it.

Here is my code:

```
T = int(input())
for j in range(1,T+1):
    N, C = map(int, input().split())
    minimumC = N - 1
    maximumC = 3 * (N - 3) + 4
    halfWayPoint = N + N - 2
    startNums = [i for i in range(1, N + 1)]

    if C < minimumC or C > maximumC:
        print(f"Case #{j}: IMPOSSIBLE")
        continue

    # N > 3
    if N > 3:
        if minimumC <= C and C < halfWayPoint:
            howManyToReverse = C - N
            startNums[-howManyToReverse - 1:] = reversed(startNums[-howManyToReverse - 1:])

        elif C == halfWayPoint:
            startNums = startNums[::-1]

        else:
            startNums = startNums[::-1]
            leftPointer = 1
            rightPointer = N - 2

            if (C - halfWayPoint) % 2 != 0:
                print(f"Case #{j}: IMPOSSIBLE")
                continue
            else:
                numberOfSwaps = (C - halfWayPoint) / 2
                while numberOfSwaps > 0:
                    startNums[leftPointer], startNums[rightPointer] = startNums[rightPointer], startNums[leftPointer]
                    numberOfSwaps -= 1

        ans = " ".join(list(map(str,startNums)))
        print(f"Case #{j}: {ans}")

    # edge case, N = 2 or 3
    else:
        if N == 2:
            if C == 1:
                print(f"Case #{j}: {int(1)} {int(2)}")
            elif C == 2:
                print(f"Case #{j}: {int(2)} {int(1)}")
            else:
                print(f"Case #{j}: IMPOSSIBLE")

        elif N == 1:
            if C == 0:
                print(f"Case #{j}: {int(0)}")
            else:
                print(f"Case #{j}: IMPOSSIBLE")
```

When I run a test case against the code, for example:

```
5
4 6
2 1
7 12
7 2
2 1000
```

The output that I get is:

```
5
4 6
2 1
7 12
7 2
2 1000Case #1: 4 3 2 1
Case #2: 1 2
Case #3: 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
Case #4: IMPOSSIBLE
```

For some reason, the first line of output is overlapping with the last line of the input, and also the last input, i.e. Case #5 is not printing.

I have come across this problem when solving other problems too when they have involved `input()`. Any ideas how to fix this, and where I am going wrong?

Comment: Can you share how you're running the script and providing input? The code you've given doesn't print the input values as part of the output, and running it is giving me all 5 cases.

Comment: I am running the script on Pycharm as is above, and then for the input, I am running it one line at a time, i.e. I type '5' then hit 'enter', then '4' '6' then hit enter, etc

Answer (score 0):

when you take input form user, you can get all input from user and save it to matrix. it will be best for competition like codejam, ieee xtreme, and other hackthons

and after u can use that input to run your application

Here is your code(after i change your input part):

```
inputmat = []
T = int(input())
for x in range(0, T):
    inputmat.append(list(map(int, input().split())))

for j in range(1,T+1):
    N = inputmat[j-1][0]
    C = inputmat[j - 1][0]
    minimumC = N - 1
    maximumC = 3 * (N - 3) + 4
    halfWayPoint = N + N - 2
    startNums = [i for i in range(1, N + 1)]

    if C < minimumC or C > maximumC:
        print(f"Case #{j}: IMPOSSIBLE")
        continue

    # N > 3
    if N > 3:
        if minimumC <= C and C < halfWayPoint:
            howManyToReverse = C - N
            startNums[-howManyToReverse - 1:] = reversed(startNums[-howManyToReverse - 1:])

        elif C == halfWayPoint:
            startNums = startNums[::-1]

        else:
            startNums = startNums[::-1]
            leftPointer = 1
            rightPointer = N - 2

            if (C - halfWayPoint) % 2 != 0:
                print(f"Case #{j}: IMPOSSIBLE")
                continue
            else:
                numberOfSwaps = (C - halfWayPoint) / 2
                while numberOfSwaps > 0:
                    startNums[leftPointer], startNums[rightPointer] = startNums[rightPointer], startNums[leftPointer]
                    numberOfSwaps -= 1

        ans = " ".join(list(map(str,startNums)))
        print(f"Case #{j}: {ans}")

    # edge case, N = 2 or 3
    else:
        if N == 2:
            if C == 1:
                print(f"Case #{j}: {int(1)} {int(2)}")
            elif C == 2:
                print(f"Case #{j}: {int(2)} {int(1)}")
            else:
                print(f"Case #{j}: IMPOSSIBLE")

        elif N == 1:
            if C == 0:
                print(f"Case #{j}: {int(0)}")
            else:
                print(f"Case #{j}: IMPOSSIBLE")
```